# PowerBuilder - TreeViewItem issue

Tags: treeview, tree, powerbuilder, expand

I am using PB 10.5

How can I hide the expand symbol (+) in a TreeViewItem object (if the node has not subnodes)???

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so fast. You have to modify the 'Children' property, just like this:

```
treeviewitem my_tvi

if Not IsValid(ids_childrens) then
    ids_childrens = CREATE datastore
    ids_childrens.DataObject = 'my_dw'
    ids_childrens.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
end if
num_children = ids_childrens.Retrieve(long(some_pk))
if num_children <= 0 then
    my_tvi.children = false
else
    my_tvi.children = true          
end if
```